# How to define table loading order with DBIc Schema deploy()

Tags: mysql, perl, foreign-keys, dbix-class

I am wrapping a database schema using the DBIc Schema to help with unit testing the code.

Based on the original database I used `dbidump` to to generate the schema from the database:

```
dbicdump -o dump_directory=./lib -o components='["InflateColumn::DateTime"]' -o debug=1 Test::Schema 'dbi:mysql:dbname=mcdowall_test' 'test'
```

There are 2 InnoDB tables `table_a` and `table_b`. The issue is that `table_a` has a foreign key constraint on table `table_b`:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_b` (
  `table_b_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `source_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`table_b_id`),
  KEY (`source_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `table_a` (
  `table_a_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `source_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`table_a_id`),
  KEY (`table_a_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ab`
    FOREIGN KEY (`source_id`)
    REFERENCES `table_b` (`source_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

This means that the when using `deploy()` to install the schema during testing it installs the tables in alphabetical order:

```
use Test::Schema

my $schema = Test::Schema->connect($dsn, $user, $pass, \%opts);
$schema->deploy();
```

This raises the following SQL error as `table_b` does not exist when `table_a` is getting created:

```
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Is there a way to get the `deploy()` function to either pre-check the foreign key dependencies or specify specific tables to be inserted first?

Ideally `table_b` should be installed first and then `table_a`.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @AlexanderHartmaier I am using MySQL with InnoDB tables.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the query was sensitive to the order as there was a missing index when defining the second table. In the example in the description the definition for `table_a` was the same, but the definition for `table_b` was:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_b` (
  `table_b_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `source_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`table_b_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

When run in the order of `table_b` and then `table_a` everything is fine. If the calls are made in the order of `table_a` then `table_b`, because there is a missing index on the `source_id` in the definition of `table_b` then the query fails whether the `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` is set to 0 or 1.

Found this by turning on the debug() setting in DBIc to find the queries it ran and then using this [post](https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/04/06/dealing-mysql-error-code-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint/) on the Percona blog to whittle down the issues and find the answer.

In the table definition I then used the `sqlt_deploy_hook` below the boiler plate code created by the Schema Loader to add the index:

```
sub sqlt_deploy_hook {
   my ($self, $sqlt_table) = @_;

   $sqlt_table->add_index(name => 'table_b_idx_source_id', fields => ['source_id']);
}
```

Thank you for those that have looked at this question or taken time to consider the issue.